# INSERT INTO multiple tables through multiple foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I have multiple table connected together by a few different foreign keys (see attahced image).
[image: TABLES]

I am trying to insert into the projects table. I've been trying to accomplish this through the following code below, but it's not working. Right now I am getting an error saying that neither client_id_fk, project_manager_id_fk have a value. That makes sense since I didn't include them in the insert, but aren't auto incrementing and I also can't just add a random int to those fields since that throws an error as well. It technically works if I set the client_id_fk and project_manager_id_fk to NULL, but then there's no data in the other tables...Please help

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO PROJECTS (Project_Name, StartDate) VALUES( '".$_POST["Project_Name"]."','".$_POST["StartDate"]."')";
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO CLIENTS(Client_Name, Client_Email, Client_Phone) VALUES ('".$_POST["Client_Name"]."','".$_POST["Client_Email"]."','".$_POST["Client_Phone"]."')";
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO PROJECT_MANAGERS(ProjectManager_Name,Project_Manager_Email, Project_Manager_Phone) VALUES ('".$_POST["ProjectManager_Name"]."','email', 'phone')";     
$sql4 = "INSERT INTO TYPE_OF_WORK(TypeOfWork) VALUES ('".$_POST["TypeOfWork"]."')";
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Change the order of your `INSERT` swap $sql1 and $sql3, you have to first add clients and product_managers in order for projects to be added.

Comment: Your code is _**wide open** to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)_. Don't build queries by sticking strings together. Instead, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern:

```sql
    -- Insert data into slave tables
INSERT INTO slave_1 (columns_1) VALUES ('values_1');
INSERT INTO slave_2 (columns_2) VALUES ('values_2');
    -- Insert data into main table, 
    -- query FK values from slaves 
    -- using values inserted above 
    -- as filtering conditions
INSERT INTO main (columns_main, fk_column_1, fk_column_2)
SELECT 'values_main', slave_1.id, slave_2.id
    FROM ( SELECT id FROM slave_1 WHERE columns_1 = 'values_1' ) slave_1
    JOIN ( SELECT id FROM slave_2 WHERE columns_2 = 'values_2' ) slave_2
```

If it is possible that some subquery in last INSERT may return more than 1 row then wrap output column in this subquery into `MAX()` function (you will receive `id` for the last row matched - i.e. just inserted).

Comment: What exactly am I wrapping the MAX() function around? Everything works, but like you predicted I am sometimes receiving more than 1 row. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure why MAX would ever be the right thing to use here; if you have multiple candidates for the "slave" tables (not the best name!) that's a sign that either the WHERE clause isn't precise enough, or you've gone wrong somewhere modelling your data.

Comment: @IMSoP *if you have multiple candidates* then you have two rows in your slave table which differs in one column only - but this is illogical. *What exactly am I wrapping the MAX() function around?* `MAX(id)` instead of `id`.

Comment: @Akina Like I say, the solution to that is to fix the where clause to mention the column that differs, or delete one of the rows if they are complete duplicates, not to use mathematical operations on an ID which should have no meaning.

Comment: @IMSoP Not look at your "- If it's a new Client, you need to insert that before the Project; if it's a new Project Manager, you need to insert that before the Project too. Once you've inserted them, you need to get their IDs, e.g. with the LAST_INSERT_ID() function. - If it's an existing Client and/or Project Manager, you need to look up their IDs based on whatever logic makes sense in your application." This is absolutely the same - except 1)your solution uses additional queries and additional intermediate PHP variables 2) my solution is free of connection resetting problem.

Comment: @Akina The only part of your answer I was questioning is the mention of `MAX()` - there should be no situation where you need to specify `MAX(id)`, which is effectively picking at random between duplicates. Nor did I say anything in my answer about PHP variables, I just outlined the principle. Although looking at it now, you also have a `JOIN` with no `ON`, which is invalid - you probably want the sub-queries to be directly in the `SELECT` clause rather than `FROM` and `JOIN`. And a simpler solution would be to use functions to get the last inserted ID, although those do vary between DBMSes.

Comment: @IMSoP *you also have a JOIN with no ON, which is invalid* This is valid in MySQL. But you may add `ON 1=1` if this is critical. *a simpler solution would be to use functions to get the last inserted ID* As I have said - until connection reset. And additionally - while there is one slave only, or you need in intermediate variables. *The only part of your answer I was questioning is the mention of MAX()* - no problems, `LIMIT 1` will solve too (with ordering or without it).

Comment: @Akina You're still not listening to my point: if you need MAX, or LIMIT, or anything of the sort, *something has gone wrong somewhere*. In this case, either the two rows represent different project managers, and the program should know the difference between them, or the two rows represent the same project manager, which is a bug.

Comment: @IMSoP Basic phrase: "If it is possible that some subquery in last INSERT may return more than 1 row". Now please prove me that **all** columns except PK AI are inserted into slaves. Take into account that the row may contain columns which are NOT listed in INSERT (they are NULLable or/and they have DEFAULT value), and the rows may differ in that not listed columns. I.e. we CANNOT to distinguish the row inserted just now and the row which was inserted far ago while using only inserted columns values, but we can do while looking the whole row.

Comment: @Akina If you can distinguish the row based on other columns, then the solution is to include those columns in the WHERE clause, that's what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

Step back and think about the relationships you're modelling. You have told MySQL that a Project has a Client and a Project Manager; that makes sense. Then you've tried to insert a Project with only this information:

```
INSERT INTO PROJECTS (Project_Name, Start_Date) ...
```

The error you're getting is asking you "which Client is this Project for, and who is the Project Manager?" That's something only you can know.

- If it's a new Client, you need to insert that *before the Project*; if it's a new Project Manager, you need to insert that before the Project too. Once you've inserted them, you need to get their IDs, e.g. with [the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).
- If it's an existing Client and/or Project Manager, you need to look up their IDs based on whatever logic makes sense in your application.

Once you have those two IDs, you can create you Project:

```
INSERT INTO PROJECTS (Project_Name, Start_Date, Client_Id, Project_Manager_Id) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO PROJECTS (Project_Name, StartDate) VALUES( '".$_POST["Project_Name"]."','".$_POST["StartDate"]."')";
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO CLIENTS(Client_Name, Client_Email, Client_Phone) VALUES ('".$_POST["Client_Name"]."','".$_POST["Client_Email"]."','".$_POST["Client_Phone"]."')";
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO PROJECT_MANAGERS(ProjectManager_Name,Project_Manager_Email, Project_Manager_Phone) VALUES ('".$_POST["ProjectManager_Name"]."','email', 'phone')";     
$sql4 = "INSERT INTO TYPE_OF_WORK(TypeOfWork) VALUES ('".$_POST["TypeOfWork"]."')";
```

Because you are trying to `INSERT` into `projects` a `client.id` and a `project_manager.id` that does not exist in the database. So the above should actually be written like this (in case you use [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)):

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

/* check connection */
if (!$link) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

// First add the client in case the table is completely empty
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO clients(name, email, phone) VALUES (?,?,?);");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $_POST["Client_Name"], $_POST["Client_Email"], $_POST["Client_Phone"]);
/* execute prepared statement */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
/* close statement and connection */
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

// Then add the project_manager in case the table is completely empty
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO project_managers(name, email, phone) VALUES (?,?,?);");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $_POST["ProjectManager_Name"], 'email', 'phone');
/* execute prepared statement */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
/* close statement and connection */
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

// Also add the type_of_work in case the table is completely empty
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO type_of_work(TypeOfWork) VALUES (?);");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $_POST["TypeOfWork"]);
/* execute prepared statement */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
/* close statement and connection */
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

// Finally add your project
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO projects (project_name, start_date, client_id, project_manager_id) SELECT ?,?,client.id,project_managers.id FROM client,project_managers WHERE client.name = ? AND client.email = ? AND client.phone = ? AND project_managers.name = ?;");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssss', $_POST["Project_Name"],$_POST["StartDate"],$_POST["Client_Name"], $_POST["Client_Email"], $_POST["Client_Phone"],$_POST["ProjectManager_Name"]);
/* execute prepared statement */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
/* close statement and connection */
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
```